# Need a solution for altenating sections

Tags: php

I can't think of a feasible solution to create alternating sections for a PHP template for each course on a restaurant's menu page. I want to create a template that would achieve this result:

```
<section class="well well__off1>
<div>Starters</div>
.... menu list ...
</section>

<section class="bg-secondary well well__off1>
<div>Mains</div>
.... menu list ...
</section>

<section class="well well__off1>
<div>Steaks</div>
.... menu list ...
</section>

etc
etc
```

The current template that I am running is this. How do I alternate the CSS sections for each Course?

```
<section class="well well__off1">
    <div class="grid_8">
      <?php foreach ($MDayMeals as $courses => $meals): ?>
      <h4><?php echo $courses; ?></h4>
      <?php foreach ($meals as $meal): ?> 
        <div class="name-wrap">
         <?php echo htmlencode($meal['name_of_dish']) ?>
        </div>
          <?php endforeach ?> 
        <?php endforeach ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this?

Thanks
Terry

Comment: is this code in a loop as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <?php $even = false; ?>
  <?php foreach ($MDayMeals as $courses => $meals): ?>
    <?php $class = ( $even ) ? 'bg-secondary ' : ''; ?>
    <?php $even = !$even; ?>
  <section class="$class well well__off1">
    <div class="grid_8">
      <h4><?php echo $courses; ?></h4>
      <?php foreach ($meals as $meal): ?> 
        <div class="name-wrap">
          <?php echo htmlencode($meal['name_of_dish']) ?>
        </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?> 
    </div>
  </section>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: This works perfectly for the exact code I posted which are for a few menu pages.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help:

```
  <?php foreach ($MDayMeals as $courses => $meals): ?>
    <?php if($i%2===0): //check value odd or even 
    ?>
  <section class="well well__off1">
<?php else:?>
  <section class="bg-secondary well well__off1">
<?php endif;?>
  <div class="grid_8">
  <h4><?php echo $courses; ?></h4>
  <?php foreach ($meals as $meal): ?> 
    <div class="name-wrap">
     <?php echo htmlencode($meal['name_of_dish']) ?>

    </div>
      <?php endforeach ?> 
       </div>
  </section>
  <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: This works perfectly for several other pages which I did not post here. However, I am getting an error message "Undefined variable i". How do I rectify that? Assigning value 1 or 0 to $i before the loop starts does not work.